# Install a BigCommerce Stencil Theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I have developed two Stencil themes following the BigCommerce online docs.

As of to date: how does one go about installing a theme developed against Stencil on BigCommerce?

After filling out the upload request form (as instructed) and bouncing around with their tech support all night and morning -- who insisted on pointing me to docs on how to use a customizer.

I am being told installation of custom Stencil themes is not possible (?) until June.

Please tell me this is just a misinformed rep.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pending feature, as you were told. Currently, custom theme uploads have to be done manually by a member of the BigCommerce staff. The upload request form goes to the team that has the ability to do so, but is actively limited by bandwidth since it is uncommon for a developer to need only a single upload.

Some information about this is listed under [our new and pending features page](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/new-and-pending-features).

Comment: [Edit] I filled out the form and called to get status. I was just told by BigCommerce that customization to Stencil was not possible out side the customizer, and moreover uploaded versions were not possible. How do we  obtain the assist of the proper support personnel to do so?

Comment: The form you already filled out was sufficient. It will be reviewed. Our technical support staff is not the best point of contact for developers.

Comment: Awesome. That's a relief. I will standby. Thanks.

Comment: what is the average lead time for these installs? And will we be able to update the code for minor changes after it is loaded?

Comment: @Alyss I would like to know the same thing. Do we need to go through this process every time a minor change is needed to a custom theme? For example if I need to make a small layout change, do I need to bundle theme, send it to you, and wait a few days until the changes are live?

Comment: @flyingL123 right now, yes. We have to manually upload for each new bundle/small change. We are working on releasing the upload feature for developers and merchants in the short term.

Comment: @Alyss Could we enable the installed theme to be editable by WebDav, or maybe allow override patches to be applied and upload via WebDav?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. WebDAV is host to blueprint template files only and Stencil assets are separate due to the system architecture.