# How to upload or submit BigCommerce Stencil Theme on Bigcommerce store

Tags: bigcommerce

I have developed Bigcommerce Stencil theme as per the available online document.

I wanted to test that theme on demo store of bigcommerce, what is the way to upload that theme on demo store?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701914/install-a-bigcommerce-stencil-theme

Comment: Check out following links -

https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Opting-in-to-Stencil/
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Custom-Theme-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

Given below is the command to bundle and push your theme to your store.

```
stencil push
```

Note that before using this, you need to configure your API credentials in your .stencil file

```
{
  "normalStoreUrl": "<URL of your website here>",
  "port": "3001",
  "clientId": "<Client ID from API Access>",
  "accessToken": "<Access Token from API Access>",
  "customLayouts": {
    "brand": {},
    "category": {},
    "page": {},
    "product": {}
  }
}
```